# How to stretch QLabel in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, qlabel

How to change the following code to get the QLabel stretch to width of the window ?

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 100)
    self.label = QLabel('Hello World!', self)
    self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; background-color: red')
    self.show()

app = QApplication([])
win = Window()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation about QMainWindow [says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details), you *must* set a central widget for it:

> Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder.

The problem is that you need a [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) in order to properly adapt widget sizes inside a parent, and just manually setting widget geometries is generally discouraged.

You created the label as a direct child, so it will have no knowledge about its parents size changes.
Just set the label as central widget.

```
    self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
```

Otherwise, you can use a *container* widget, set a layout and add the label to it, but you still must set the central widget.

```
central = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(central)
layout.addWidget(self.label)
self.setCentralWidget(central)
```

The alternative is to directly use a QWidget instead of QMainWindow as you did in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sizePolicy

```
self.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
```

Comment: Here is what I did and what happened https://i.imgur.com/Uzb4LoM.png so it didn't give any help.

Comment: SizePolicy is dependent on parent layout. and for QMainWindow, you need to set the central widget and add the label to that. Otherwise the widget will be hovering.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. The problem is now solved by the following code changes

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Window(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()    
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 100)
    self.label = QLabel('Hello World!', self)
    self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; background-color: red')

    self.box_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.box_layout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.setLayout(self.box_layout)

    self.show()

app = QApplication([])
win = Window()
app.exec()
```

**Edit:** laytout -> box_layout

Comment: Please consider that `layout` is an existing function of all QWidgets, and you should not overwrite it with another value.

Comment: What do you mean ?
The net is full of examples using setLayout() in a class what is derived from the QWidget class. How I understand this if you don't use setLayout() then you have to change the existing layout until you can use another type layouts in a new widgets. Or how would you change the above code to get it work ?

Comment: Please read more carefully: I was referring to the *function* that is *named* [`layout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout), which is the access function of all QWidget subclasses, and you shouldn't overwrite that function name with your own variable (even if it still refers to the widget's layout). It's preferable to use something else like `self.myLayout`, or just use a local variable instead of the instance attribute, since (my point exactly) you can access it later using that *existing function* `self.layout()`.

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad. Thx.